# Running HTTP and HTTPS side-by-side in Rails (local) Development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, https, thin

I have a Rails application that contains some urls that must be secured with HTTPS/SSL and some that must be accessible through HTTP.

I am using Thin, and starting it with the --ssl flag means it only supports HTTPS, and any HTTP requests are not handled. I am using force_ssl to force ssl on particular URLs. As far as I understand it I need to modify Apache somehow.

How can I get both HTTP and HTTPS working in my (local) Development environment?

Answer (score 1):

As I recall it isn't possible to have https and http running on one site- for a start they are listening for different ports, so practically you are looking at dividing your content into two different parts, one for the http site and the other for the https. You could  point both sites at the same application ( so the home directory for both is the same ) but you would need to be quite careful if you choose to do that to ensure that you check that the secured files are only accessed through HTTPS and it would be very easy to accidentally introduce a security problem. The upside is that your assets could be available in both locations so that you don't have to have warnings pop up about unsecured content in a secured area and so on. If you need enough security to justify HTTPS then it is worth being aware of the risks that two ways of accessing a single location introduce. Also, as I recall ( and it is a couple of years since I worked with this so someone will probably correct me ) none of the client-side authentication will be preserved between the regular and secure area as the browser sees them as two different sites.

[Configuring Apache to serve HTTP and HTTPS for the same address](http://lookit.typepad.com/lookit/2010/04/how-to-get-apache-to-do-both-http-and-https-on-one-ip-address.html)